# Sweetalert2 with International Telephone Input, keyboard problem

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2, intl-tel-input

I'm making use of two libraries in my web app:

Sweetalert2: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2

International Telephone Input: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-inputhttps://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

However, when I initialise the input I lose the keyboard input on the drop down country list.

At the site's demo page (https://intl-tel-input.com) you can use either the keyboard arrows, or begin to type the name of a country to select the option. When I add the input into a SweetAlert2 modal, I lose this functionality and I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me why this might be, and what I can do to resolve the matter?

I've upgraded all the dependencies and minimised the options for both plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an option in SweetAlert2 that I'd missed, ensure `stopKeydownPropagation: false`